# Azure Devops CI/CD CodeCoverage with yml

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, code-coverage, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have tried to create a code coverage for my webapi. I have followed [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/run-quality-tests-build-pipeline/6-perform-code-coverage).

I have changed the YML file and got the below build failed error in Azure Devops.

[image]

I have used the following code for this. How to fix this?

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build project'
  inputs:
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory) --configuration Release'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Install .NET Core tools from local manifest'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: tool
    arguments: 'restore'

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Unit Tests'
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*Tests*.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'

    arguments: '--no-build --configuration $(buildConfiguration) /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura /p:CoverletOutput=$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/TestResults/Coverage/'
    publishTestResults: true
    projects: '**/*.Tests.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Create code coverage report'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: tool
    arguments: 'run reportgenerator -reports:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml -targetdir:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/CodeCoverage -reporttypes:HtmlInline_AzurePipelines'

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  displayName: 'Publish code coverage report'
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: 'cobertura'
    summaryFileLocation: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml'
```

Comment: Line 17 and 18 of your output tell you what the problem is. The path you are specifying is not valid and can't find any reports. I can't tell from your YAML what tool `reportgenerator` is so it would be hard for me to detail a fix.

Comment: Hi @mohan, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your Unit Test task places the output under `$(Build.BinariesDirectory)`, but your reports task specifies `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`. Now, this may be correct if binaries are within source, but without those values, I can't be sure.

I'd rule out I would verify that the file exists where you expect it to be. Try adding this to your pipeline before the coverage task:

```
  - pwsh: |
      Write-Host "Checking Sources"
      Get-ChildItem $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/coverage.cobertura.xml -Recurse
      Write-Host "Checking Binaries"
      Get-ChildItem $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/coverage.cobertura.xml -Recurse
```

Run the pipeline again and look at the log output for that task. If the file exists, then it could be related to the tool installation.

Comment: Thanks for the Help ! It's not working as expected

Comment: What's not working? Can you include some of the log output?

Comment: I got the below error .Build failed with in a sec after I added the above line .        /azure-pipelines.yml: (Line: 47, Col: 5, Idx: 1185) - (Line: 47, Col: 6, Idx: 1186): While parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key.

Comment: Try changing "pwsh" to "powershell" - I figured you were on a hosted agent, and that would be available. If that doesn't work, please post the whole section of YAML for context!